# Django 2.2 - change with of related auto_complete field on admin form

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to change the **field width** of a `related auto_complete` field. So that the *selected* record is shown a bit wider.

```
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--admin-autocomplete select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" style="width: 260px;">
 // ...
></span>
```

I created my own form and tried fiddling with `widget.attrs` (inside the init) but it has zero effect. Which itself is no strange, since these are all span elements rendered.

```
class OrderLineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fields['product'].widget.attrs.update({'stytle': 'width: 400px'})
        self.fields['product'].widget.attrs.update({'width': 400})
```

I was also looking which widget is being used, but didn't find it either. Djanog docs do explainThe `form.Select` is a simple dropdown list, which does not provide auto complete functionality.

I also tried changing some css for `.select2` class, but seems to gave no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you can change size of both, selected and diplayed options on the autocomplete widget to fit the complete text size.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AutocompleteSelect

class OrderLineForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = '__all__'

        widgets = {
            'product': AutocompleteSelect(
                YourModel._meta.get_field('product').remote_field,
                admin.site,
                attrs={'data-dropdown-auto-width': 'true', 'style': "width: 100%;"}
            ),
        }
```